# Sorting OPTIONS within a multiple display SELECT tag breaks with newer browsers

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, browser

On some websites I use code to sort `<OPTION>` values within `<SELECT>` fields.

The sorting and display used to work fine, however, with some recent browser updates (in Opera and Chrome), these now no longer display correctly and are displaying some weird functionality issues within the browser.

I created a [jsBin](https://jsbin.com/heceduneqo/edit?html,console,output) to give an example.

On the jsBin, you can see in the console that all elements are sorted correctly, however, the display is not correct within the `<SELECT>` element.

Below is the code that I would use to sort `<SELECT><OPTION>` fields:

```
//HTML
<a href="#" onClick="sortNames(); return false">Sort Names</a><br />
<br />
<select id="sortable_select" multiple>
  <option>John Doe</option>
  <option>Jane Doe</option>
  <option>Mikey Mike</option>
  <option>First Last</option>
</select>

<script>
  //JQuery
  function sortNames() {
    var sortedList = $('#sortable_select option').sort(sortList);
    $('#sortable_select').html(sortedList);
  }
  function sortList(a,b) {
    var a = a.text;
    var b = b.text;
    return a === b ? 0 : a < b ? -1 : 1;
  }
</script>
```

Again, please see the [jsBin](https://jsbin.com/heceduneqo/edit?html,console,output) to see a live example.

If you are running CHROME preversion 81, this will probably work for you. Same with Opera pre version 68.

This runs fine in Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0, and used to run fine in previous versions of Chrome and Opera.

Comment: It seems with a recent chrome update, this issue is now resolved. I am sure the update will make its way to opera as well. Closing as the browsers seems to be fixing the issue. (edit: it appears I can not close my own question)